# Adding dependency with version of the current build in SBT?

Tags: sbt

In sbt, how can I add a dependency that has the same version as the current build, e.g.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel" %% "something" % {projectversion}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel" %% "something" % version.value
```

Comment: In SBT 0.12: `libraryDependencies <<= version { v => "com.sksamuel" %% "something" % v }`

Comment: Wow no wonder everyone is bamboozled by SBT. At least the 0.13 one is sensible so things are going in the right direction.